# Error when trying to use async.concat to retrieve data from redis

Tags: asynchronous, node.js, redis

I was following an example posted by the async author [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579999/for-loop-over-event-driven-code/4594248#4594248) but I'm getting an error.

- redis-2.2.12
- node v0.4.11-pre

Here's my code:

```
var async = require('async');
var redis = require('redis');

var keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];

var client = redis.createClient();
var multi = client.multi();
for (var key in keys) {
  multi.hmset(key, {'some': 'value'});
}
multi.exec(function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.dir(res);

  var myCallback = function(err, res) {
    console.log('in myCallback');
    console.dir(res);
    client.quit();
    process.exit();
  };
 async.concat(keys, client.hgetall, myCallback);
});
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ node redis_test.js
[ 'OK', 'OK', 'OK' ]

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'send_command'
    at /home/project/node_modules/redis/index.js:666:25
    at /home/project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:508:13
    at /home/project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:97:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /home/project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:26:24
    at /home/project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:96:9
    at /home/project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:507:9
    at Object.concat (/home/project/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:141:23)
    at /home/project/redis_test.js:21:9
    at Command.callback (/home/project/node_modules/redis/index.js:827:13)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When async runs `client.hgetall`, it trashes the value of `this` inside of `hgetall`.  You can either wrap up an anonymous function to glue this together, or use `fn.bind()` as shown below.

You also want to avoid using `for .. in` to iterate over an Array.  Use either a regular for loop or `arr.forEach()`.  Your example would have mysteriously failed as written.  Here's a version that seems to do what you want:

```
var async = require('async');
var redis = require('redis');
var keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'];

var client = redis.createClient();
var multi = client.multi();
keys.forEach(function (key) {
  multi.hmset(key, {'some': 'value'});
});
multi.exec(function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.dir(res);

  var myCallback = function(err, res) {
    console.log('in myCallback');
    console.dir(res);
    client.quit();
    process.exit();
  };
 async.concat(keys, client.hgetall.bind(client), myCallback);
});
```

This outputs:

```
[ 'OK', 'OK', 'OK' ]
in myCallback
[ { some: 'value' },
  { some: 'value' },
  { some: 'value' } ]
```

To debug the mysterious failure, you can turn on debug logging in `node_redis` by doing `redis.debug_mode = true;` before sending any Redis commands.